# iOS8 interactive UILocaNotification- how to hide alertAction from alert options

Tags: ios8, uilocalnotification

[image]I have implemented iOS8 based interactive UILocalNotification in one of my apps. We needed to change the default text, unlock  in "Slide to unlock.." to "respond". In order to achieve that, I added an alertAction called "respond" while creating the notifications, and it works great. 
`localNotification.alertAction = "respond"`

However, this is causing an undue problem for me. I only need Option1, Option2 as alert options but now, "respond" comes up as one more option at the top, which is what I don't need.

Is there a way to remove "respond" from the alert action but keep it in the lock text as a replacement of "unlock". Is this even possible? I looked at the API and did not find anything useful.

NB: I wonder if it's not possible at all? - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertAction - says,

alertAction
 Property
The title of the action button or slider.

Declaration
SWIFT
`var alertAction: String?`
Discussion
Assign a string or, preferably, a localized-string key (using NSLocalizedString) as the value. The alert action is the title of the right button of the alert or the value of the unlock slider, where the value replaces “unlock” in “slide to unlock”. If you specify nil, and alertBody is non-nil, “View” (localized to the preferred language) is used as the default value.

Comment: You provided much description but better you post the code as well..

Comment: Wow, not a single answer yet?

Comment: Your question is talking about `UILocalNotification` but the image you show is about `UIAlertController`. Which is it that you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two articles describing the possibilities :

ObjC : [UIAlertController Changes in iOS 8](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html)

SWIFT : [UIAlert​Controller in IOS8](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/)

```
respondAction.enabled = NO;
```

Here is some code when the button is hidden until you enter the desired number of characters in the textField :

```
- (void)alertTextFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender
{
  UIAlertController *alertController = (UIAlertController *)self.presentedViewController;
  if (alertController)
  {
    UITextField *login = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
    UIAlertAction *okAction = alertController.actions.lastObject;
    okAction.enabled = login.text.length > 2;
  }
}
```